# How do I get username by user_id in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

**I have this view and loop in my templates:**

```
def home(request):
    entries = Entries.objects.all()
    context = {"entries": entries}
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

**index.html:**

```
{% for entry in entries %}
{{ entry.user_id }}
{% endfor %}
```

I can get the `user_id` of the entries to output. But how do I get the `username` for that `user_id`? I don't know how to get that information in my view.

Comment: Can you post the `Entries` model? because if it contains a ForeignKey to user it will be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better if you have a `ForeignKey` to `User` in your `Entries` model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Entries(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User) # instead of user_id = IntegerField()
```

If you don't want that, you can add a property to your model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Entries(models.Model):
    @property
    def user(self):
        return User.objects.get(pk=self.user_id)
```

This property makes the user available as `entry.user` as if it were an attribute, so:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
    {{ entry.user.username }}
{% endfor %}
```